# Can't draw 1px line

Tags: createjs, easeljs

`createjs.Shape()` with graphics `setStrokeStyle(1)` draws a 2px line instead of 1px. If you screenshot the JSfiddle output below, you will seee that the line is 2px tall.

http://jsfiddle.net/7fbr9yan/

How do I draw a 1px line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that you draw in going in between two lines of pixels, so it's coloring both sides of it in grey instead of black.
change your code to

```
line.graphics.moveTo(20,74.5).setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("#000").lineTo(280,74.5);
```

in order to draw over only one line of pixels.

Comment: If you like using whole numbers, just offset the shape's x/y position by 0.5.

Comment: I've often found when using createjs and Flash in the past that if I wanted pixel perfect results that didn't run into negative fractional space to use drawRect instead. i.e. [http://jsfiddle.net/7fbr9yan/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/7fbr9yan/2/)